# PHP - MySQL extension which is required by WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My wordpress home page is okay but when i access wp-admin it returns mysql extension error. I'm using PHP 5.6 on a shared hosting without terminal access. I already changed the PHP version in cpanel to PHP 5.6

php.ini file

```
; cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
; Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
; To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> 
Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
; For more information, read our documentation 
(https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)

allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
asp_tags = Off
display_errors = On
enable_dl = On
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = 256M
post_max_size = 8M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
upload_max_filesize = 64M
zlib.output_compression = Off

extension=mysql.so
extension=mysqli.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

php info output:
[image: Here is my php info]

Error:
[image]

Comment: It is probably `extension=mysql.so`. I can't quite understand why are you using it at all. [This article](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/articles/mysql-php2-139190.html) says that it's outdated, and thew newer ones are `mysqli.so` and `pdo_mysql.so`. So probably comment that? (`;extension=mysql.so`)

Comment: already commented it, but the error still persists when going to /wp-admin

Comment: Could you add the error message to the post?

Comment: added it already :(  it says Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

Comment: what version of wordpress?

Comment: Interesting, Wordpress thinks that the nessesary MySql extention is not installed. Either it's configured wrong,or it's really not installed. The nessesary MySql extention greatly depends on WP version